# Error adding geom_errorbar in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I'm trying to add some errorbars to my scattergraph and I can't work out what's wrong. Code below:

```
growth_means <- read.csv("growth_means.csv")

plot = ggplot() + 
  geom_point(aes(x=HAS, y=Width, colour=Genotype), 
             size=1.5, data=growth_means, stat="identity") + 
  geom_errorbar(inherit.aes = FALSE, 
                ymin=Width-Width_SE, ymax=Width-Width_SE)

plot
```

Data below:

```
> head(growth_means)


HAS DAS      Width    Width_SE    Length   Length_SE       Area     Area_SE Genotype
1 120   5 0.07021040 0.002033000 0.1064330 0.006007115 0.00593173 0.000428288       WT
2 120   5 0.09270133 0.006270253 0.1324452 0.009192732 0.01053883 0.001126512    da1-1
3 120   5 0.10211586 0.005986254 0.1468009 0.004522738 0.01273033 0.001277010       bb
4 120   5 0.10938800 0.006663103 0.1560210 0.015423139 0.01382478 0.001893295  da1-1bb
5 168   7 0.24769211 0.014692246 0.3162221 0.016811098 0.06381803 0.006592822       WT
6 168   7 0.29798890 0.007262811 0.3896144 0.009202582 0.09314732 0.001129070    da1-1
```

I can plot a perfectly good scatterplot but get:

> Error in layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom =
>   GeomErrorbar,  :    object 'Width' not found

when I run the above code.

Comment: You need to put the aesthetics that refer to variables in the dataset inside `aes`.  This is `ymin` and `ymax` in `geom_errorbar`.  If you don't want to set `x` or the dataset globally in `ggplot`, you'll also need to map `x` and define the dataset within `geom_errorbar`.

Comment: Do you mean as below?

`growth_means <- read.csv("growth_means.csv")
plot = ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=HAS, y=Width, colour=Genotype), size=1.5, data=growth_means, stat="identity") 
+ geom_errorbar(data= growth_means, aes(x=HAS, ymin=Width-Width_SE, ymax=Width-Width_SE)
plot`

Because that hasn't changed anything?

Comment: You mean it hasn't changed anything as in you are still getting the same error or your plot doesn't look right?  You have other possible coding mistakes (math for `ymin` same as `ymax`, don't color error bars to match points, etc.), but if you put in a closing parenthesis in the code in your comment it works for me.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out those other mistakes, I've fixed them now so have:

`growth_means <- read.csv("growth_means.csv")
> plot = ggplot() + geom_point(aes(x=HAS, y=Width, colour=Genotype), size=1.5, data=growth_means, stat="identity") 
>  + geom_errorbar(data= growth_means, aes(x=HAS, ymin=Width-Width_SE, ymax=Width+Width_SE))`

But get a different error now: 

Error in +geom_errorbar(data = growth_means, aes(x = HAS, ymin = Width -  : 
  invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: Your last code works for me (make sure the point line ends with a plus, though).  [Cookbook for R Graphs](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/) does a nice job of going over the basics of *ggplot2*.  You might check it out if you haven't already.  One of the topics is about plotting error bars, which might help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, seems to work now!! Cookbook for R is in my favourites bar...